# Embedded video not opening in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, youtube, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to open my video in a modal. I am creating the button  using javascript and on the click method I want to open the modal  with an embedded youtube video, but I keep getting an 404 error. WHat is my error:

I have the video id in my json and am calling the video id from there. The modal that contains the table should call the other modal with the youtube video

My code:

HTML:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="drilldown">
                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <h5 class="modal-title pull-left"></h5>
                                        <div class="pull-right">

                                            <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="cursor: pointer;">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="spin-wrapper">
                                            <div class="spinner"></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <table id="table"  class="table table-sm table-hover">
                                            <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <th>Date</th>
                                                    <th>Name</th>
                                                    <th>Youtube</th>
                                                </tr>
                                            </thead>
                                            <tbody></tbody>
                                        </table>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">


                                    <div class="modal-body">

                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                        </button>        
                                        <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
                                        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                                            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
                                        </div>


                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

JavaScript

```
json.forEach(elem => {
elem.youtube = `<a class="vl" id="${elem.video_id}" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/${elem.video_id}?autoplay=1" data-target="#myModal"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a>
 </a>`;
});

 let table = $('#table').DataTable({
        data: json,
        columns: [{
          data: 'date'
        }, {
          data: 'name'
        }, {
          data: 'youtube'
        }]
      });
});

let $videoSrc;
$('.vl').click(function() {
  console.log(this);
  $videoSrc = $(this).data("src");
  // console.log($videoSrc);
});

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {

  $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0");
})

$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $("#video").attr('src', $videoSrc);
})
```

When I click on the modal I get a 404 error.

Comment: I removed the `table>thead` markup and forgot the title config... Updated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work, but you cannot execute this here because YouTube videos trigger a cross-site warning.

> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`

I created a working demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/5xyetqw2/

```js
let json = [{
  date: '2019-04-30',
  name: 'Stack Overflow for Teams - Q&A in a Private and Secure Environment',
  video_id: 'HJtJXMKpl2g'
}, {
  date: '2019-06-04',
  name: 'Stack Overflow Talent - The Best Way to Hire Developers',
  video_id: 'PMDmo4SaP1s'
}, {
  date: '2019-07-19',
  name: 'Stack Overflow for Teams - Share Knowledge & Drive Productivity',
  video_id: 'wmzBz5WSEls'
}];

var $videoSrc = null;

json.forEach(elem => {
  elem.youtube = $('<a>', { id: elem.video_id, class: 'video_link' })
    .attr('data-toggle', 'modal')
    .attr('data-src', `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${elem.video_id}`)
    .attr('data-target', '#video-modal')
    .append($('<i>').addClass('fab fa-youtube'))[0].outerHTML;
});

let table = $('#video-table').DataTable({
  data: json,
  columns: [{
    title: 'Date',
    data: 'date'
  }, {
    title: 'Title',
    data: 'name'
  }, {
    title: 'Link',
    data: 'youtube'
  }]
});

$('#toggle-modal-btn').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.modal').first().modal('toggle');
});

$('#toggle-modal-btn').trigger('click'); // Show the table modal

$('.video_link').click(function(e) {
  $videoSrc = $(this).data('src'); // Update the video source
});

$('#video-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $("#video-frame").attr('src', $videoSrc + "?autoplay=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=0");
});

$('#video-modal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(e) {
  $("#video-frame").attr('src', $videoSrc);
});
```

```css
.video_link i {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#toggle-modal-btn {
  display: block;
  width: 8em;
  height: 2.5em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: calc(50vh - 2.5em);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<button id="toggle-modal-btn">Show Modal</button>
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="drilldown">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title pull-left"></h5>
        <div class="pull-right">
          <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="cursor: pointer;">
            <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="spin-wrapper">
          <div class="spinner"></div>
        </div>
        <table id="video-table" class="table table-sm table-hover"></table>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal fade" id="video-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video-frame" allowscriptaccess="always" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```